# accessing route helper in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When preparing a connection to the Twilio API

```
 def send_text(user, message)
    client.api.account.messages.create(
      to: user.telefono_mobile,
      from: phone_number,
      status_callback: update_twilio_reminder_url.to_s,
      body: message
    )
  end
```

The callback for the message status must be a url.  However this syntax does not access rails's helper method and returns the error `undefined local variable or method 'update_twilio_reminder_url'`

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in controller?
in newer rails (5 I guess) its also enough to call helper method by `helpers.helper_method` but I never tried it.